# Centering an image in a bootstrap carousel, while maintaining the aspect ratio, and filling the entire carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel that fills the entire browser window, and I want to have images fit the entire carousel. I got the filling up and maintaining the correct aspect-ratio part done.

Code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Carousel indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators" id = "indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>   
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class = "im">
            <img src = "images/image.jpg">

        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur…</h6>
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class = "im">
            <img src = "images/image2.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <h6>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida…</p>
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class = "im">
            <img src = "images/image3.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <h6>Praesent commodo cursus magna vel…</h6>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.im { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    position:relative;

 }
.im img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#indicators {
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

However, the problem is the image doesn't center and that looks kind of strange on smaller screens because all you're seeing is a part of the background and not the main graphic.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Heres a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/461q48by/
As you can see the image fits and the aspect ratio is maintained but the image is off center and all you can see are the frog's feet.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to add jQuery and bootstrap as external sources in jsFiddle, they can be set under Frameworks & Extensions. The fiddle not working for me the way you have it set up and you images do not all show. Also, there are no spaces when you code 'src = "images/image3.jpg", class = "I'm"' You code them like this 'src="images/image3.jpg", class="im"'

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix your syntax errors.
2. Take out your extra `</div>`'s
3. Move the closing `</div>` for the myCarousel div to the end of the carousel.  The carousel includes the carousel nav area.

Then mess with your CSS but this should take care of it.

Comment: "Mess with your CSS"? How should one mess with it, specifically?

Comment: Bootstrap does this all for you so you don't need to add width's and height's, overflows or positions in your css. If you change the closing `</p>` tag to the `</h6>` tag it should be then remove your extra `<div>` tags and move the container `<div>` to encompass the whole carousel you won't have to do any css to the interior of the carousel.  I did this to your fiddle and it works fine after.

Comment: Plus, do not use external resources for the JQuery and Bootstrap in Fiddle.  Use the frameworks and extensions drop-down on the top.